# Updating a column in table from matching data with another table

Tags: php, laravel

here is my table

[image]

[image]

there is same value between Desa/Dusun and kelurahan at both tables and i want to fill the kodepos value

*note this is just example there is lot of data

this is my code

```
public function updatekodepos()
{
    $data = DataPos::all();
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $asep) {
            KodePos::where([
                'Desa/Dusun' => $asep->kelurahan, 'kodepos' => NULL
            ])->update(['kodepos' => $asep->kodepos]);
            return redirect('/');
        }
    } else {
        return 'data not found';
    }
}
```

Model datapos represent table with kodepos value in it, and kodepos model represent the table with empty value,
any help i really appreaciate, already stuck for hours for this,
Thank you

Comment: why this is inside the for loop: return redirect('/');

Comment: @Greedo i'm sorry it's really silly lol, can you help me for one more question,how to create like condition in 'Desa/Dusun' => $asep->kelurahan, so not exactly value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return after ending your loop. When you return within the loop, then it will return after checking for the first data, whether it will match or not and update or not. You should return after checking all the data because it is within a loop.

```
public function updatekodepos()
{
    $data = DataPos::all();
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $asep) {
            KodePos::where([
                'Desa/Dusun' => $asep->kelurahan, 'kodepos' => NULL
            ])->update(['kodepos' => $asep->kodepos]);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        return 'data not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: how to create like condition in 'Desa/Dusun' => $asep->kelurahan, so not exactly value

Comment: Why do you need like a condition? Didn't you want an exact match?

Comment: KodePos::where('Desa/Dusun', 'like', '%' . $asep->kelurahan . '%')
                    ->whereNull('kodepos')
                    ->update(['kodepos' => $asep->kodepos]);